# How to project the position vector of an ellipse onto a plane?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, 3d, coordinate-systems

[image: Question]
An ellipse E is arbitrarily oriented in 3-D space with the origin at one of its foci. Use the standard elements provided in the figure. Assume the reference direction $\gamma$ is the positive Y-axis direction.
Find the projected position vector of the ellipse onto the plane of reference as a function of the angle $\nu$.

After some calculation, I obtained the position vector of the celestial body to be $$r=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos(\nu)}$$ Where $a$ is the semi-major axis and $e$ is the eccentricity.
Now, I begin with the $(r,\nu)$ coordinates in the plane of the ellipse and project it onto the reference plane using the $\cos(i)$ factor. How, then, can I find the orthogonal components $(x,y)$ of this projected position vector on the reference plane?
A parameterized solution would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to find a unit vector $\hat n$ giving the direction of the planet, and then multiply it by $r(\nu)$ given by your formula.

Suppose then your planet is at $(0,1,0)$: to carry it to its actual position $\hat n$ you need to perform first a rotation about $z$-axis by an angle $\omega+\nu$, then a rotation about $y$-axis by an angle $i$ and finally a rotation about $z$-axis by an angle $\Omega$:
$$
\hat n=
\pmatrix{\cos\Omega &-\sin\Omega & 0\\ \sin\Omega &\cos\Omega & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1}\cdot
\pmatrix{\cos i & 0 &\sin i\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -\sin i & 0 &\cos i}\cdot
\pmatrix{\cos(\omega+\nu) &-\sin(\omega+\nu) & 0\\ \sin(\omega+\nu) &\cos(\omega+\nu) & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1}\cdot
\pmatrix{0\\ 1\\0},
$$
giving the result:
$$
\hat n=
\pmatrix{-\cos i \cos\Omega \sin(\omega+\nu)-\sin\Omega \cos(\omega+\nu)\\ 
\cos\Omega \cos(\omega+\nu)-\cos i \sin \Omega\sin(\omega+\nu)\\ 
\sin i \sin(\omega+\nu)}.
$$
Multiply that by
$$
r(\nu)=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos(\nu)}
$$
and you'll have the coordinates of the planet.

Comment: Okay, so I tried to follow your logic; I understand the first rotation, but how is the second rotation about the Y axis? And isn't the third rotation about the line passing through the origin and perpendicular to the plane of the ellipse?

Comment: The second rotation is about the new position of $y$-axis after the first rotation, and so on.

Comment: @ArnavDas Try with some simple values of the angles, to see if you get the right coordinates.

Comment: Won't you have to change the matrix to rotation around the "new" Y axis? Something seems to be wrong here. Do you mind having a look at this? https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SBleJUK8auRmh6aUq4jAaBe1p8TveqlA?usp=sharing

Comment: When you rotate a vector by i, you need to do it not around the old Y axis but the new Y axis. The new Y axis is the unit vector rotated by Omega around Z. Do you know how to form the rotation matrix for such an axis?

Comment: The same probably goes for the final rotation. You need to obtain a new rotation matrix. I don't think this is a simple yaw pitch roll question.

Comment: Say, the first rotation is called Z and the second called Y. For transformation Y, Zn should be an eigenvector, because the Y rotation should be around the Zn vector as the axis. Whereas here, you've rotated it taking the original Y axis as the eigenvector.

Comment: @ArnavDas You are right, sorry: my answer is wrong, because I wrote the rotations in reverse order! Now I'll edit my answer.

Comment: okay, correct me if I’m wrong but I think this is the approach you must use to get done with it in two rotations itself: take the (0 1 0) vector, rotate by $\Omega$ around Z axis. Now, find the vector normal to the plane of the ellipse. This is the eigenvector for the second rotation, so use the [Rodrigues Rotation Formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) to get the second rotation matrix for a rotation by $\omega + \nu$. Now, your (0 1 0) vector is at the position in the figure. Could you check this approach and see if it’s right, and if so, equivalent to yours?

Comment: I verified my new formula with GeoGebra and it is correct.

Comment: You can see my code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SBleJUK8auRmh6aUq4jAaBe1p8TveqlA?usp=sharing), which is an implementation of your solution. You haven't taken the correct axes of rotations for the second and third operations. You can't rotate it around the Y axis for the second rotation, because the axis of rotation is the vector at angle $\Omega$ from the Y axis. Working it out on paper, the vectors which should be eigenvectors aren't so in your solution. Could you please check my previous response and try that solution out?

Comment: @ArnavDas What's wrong with the result you get?

Comment: @ArnavDas Here's my GeoGebra construction, in case it may be useful: https://www.geogebra.org/m/xqxxcagf

Comment: Actually, I just checked again. I think the error was being caused by some residual values of the variables. Your GeoGebra construction seems pretty right, so I think this is the correct solution. Could you elaborate more on why exactly you chose the Y axis for the second rotation? In your GeoGebra construction, 'i' causes a rotation not around the Y axis but around an axis at $\Omega$ to the Y-axis.

Comment: @ArnavDas In my GeoGebra construction the second rotation is by an angle $i$ about y-axis (green line). That axis is then rotated by $\Omega$ with the third rotation.

Comment: Oh, it wasn’t obvious to me that this rotation would’ve given the same curve. Thanks.